# How to send email in xampp localhost using PHPmailer?

Tags: xampp, phpmailer, php

I have attached two different PDF files (**mnlocalXampp** and **rnlocalXampp**) that is phpinfo of two different pcs. I have checked both information and seem that both have same information and using same version of PHP but I'm receiving email in **mnlocalXampp** but not in **rnlocalXampp**. I also activated openssl in both but i am still not receiving email in **rnlocalxampp**. Can anyone please look at both the files and let me know what difference in that files and how to configure.

```
<?php
 require 'email_class/class.phpmailer.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->IsSMTP();          //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
 $mail->Host = 'cp-in-10.webhostbox.net';    //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
 $mail->Port = '465';                //Sets the default SMTP server port
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;       //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
 $mail->Username = 'mn@infotech.com';    //Sets SMTP username
 $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';          //Sets SMTP password
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';          //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
 $mail->From = 'mn@infotech.com';          //Sets the From email address for the message
 $mail->FromName = "mn";        //Sets the From name of the message
 $mail->AddAddress("m@infotech.com");    //Adds a "To" address
 $mail->AddCC("m@infotech.com");  //Adds a "Cc" address
 $mail->WordWrap = 50;       //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
 $mail->IsHTML(true);              //Sets message type to HTML       
 $mail->Subject = 'Project CMS';       //Sets the Subject of the message
 $mail->Body = $message; //An HTML or plain text message body
 $mail->AddStringAttachment($doc, 'doc.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf'); 
 $mail->Send(); ?>
```

The above sample code is email configuration of **mnlocaXampp**. For the **rnlocalXampp** I'm using different Port(Port number: 25), Hosting, SSL enabled.

[mnlocalXampp](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19diKXCFxA4RsrJHQh6MRBF51u1kWt0On)

[rnlocalXampp](https://drive.google.com/open?id=126eW_UKD2YTQjkN4bAq4opbI1WD8FBgn)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to know where to start.

You've based your code on an obsolete example and you're using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/), and base your code on the examples provided.

You're not defining `$doc` before you use it.

`addStringAttachment` is the wrong method to use if you're trying to send a local file; use `addAttachment` instead.

The definition of `$headers` is pointless.

There's no point in CC'ing an address you're already sending to.

You have no error checking anywhere.

Resolving some of the above items may help to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Can you please check the links (**mnlocalXampp** and **rnlocalXampp**) that i have attached two documents of _phpinfo_. Actually I have no error in code and I'm also using the latest version of _PHPmailer_. The problem is that I'm receiving email in one localhost (**mnlocalXampp**) while in other I'm not receiving, that is my client (**rnlocalXampp**) pc. I think they might using proxy that's why email is not sending from my client pc.

Comment: No. You need to include all relevant information in your question. There’s no point in looking at your PHP config when you have basic mistakes in your code. You are *not* using latest PHPMailer; the latest version would not run with your code.